# For-loop iterating an array to see if a dynamically created div's id is in there, doesn't work right Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dynamic

Please help!!! I make a game quiz with flags as an exercise in JavaScript. In a container I create dynamically divs with the country names as choices. When a div is clicked the program iterates an array of objects with the right answers and if the clicked div's id is in there I want to add to the div a green border. In case of wrong a red border. I have this code:

```
x = document.getElementById("container").childNodes;

x[x.length-1].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  for(i=0; i<realNeighbours.length; i++){
    if(realNeighbours[i]['code3'].includes(e.target.id)) {
      e.target.style.border = '1px solid green';
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
    } else {
      e.target.style.border = '1px solid red';
      console.log('wrong')
    }
  }
});
```

The above code works but in case the right answers are more than one, only one  Right answer takes the green border and the other Right answers take the red border like the wrong ones. Also in the console when I click a right answer the country name appears (as it should) but also appears the "Wrong" word below the name, with a small number to the left.  Is something wrong with my for-loop?

Comment: can you also show the contents of array realNeighbours and how it is computed. Also in the code provided the event listner is only added to the last child of x. I'm assuming x is an array of all the divs(dynamically generated); shoudn't the event listener be added to all the divs or are you using event delegation somehow here?

Comment: the array is created dynamicaly  and the content is like the following:                     ```[{ "code": "AF", "code3": "AFG", "name": "Afghanistan", "number": "004" },
    { "code": "DZ", "code3": "DZA", "name": "Algeria", "number": "012" },
    { "code": "AS", "code3": "ASM", "name": "American Samoa", "number": "016" },
    { "code": "AD", "code3": "AND", "name": "Andorra", "number": "020" },]```               x is a container that holds the generated divs. The divs id is the code3 for each country. The eventListener must be to all the divs

Comment: According to the code you are only adding event listener to the last child of container.